# Different fields for GET and POST methods in REST

Tags: java, rest, dto

I have a collection /users/{userId}/tools

and I want to `GET` and `POST` to that collection. Can I have different representation of that object based on the method?

For example, for `POST` I want to send only

```
{"name": "Toolname", "material": "MaterialName"}
```

so I built a DTO with only that 2 fields.

And for`GET` I want to retrieve only the name

```
[{"name": "Toolname"}, {"name": "AnotherToolName"}, ...]
```

so I built a DTO with only the name.

Because it's the same URI, can I do that?

Comment: "can I do that?" Are you asking if it's physically possible or if doing so violates some design principle like rest?

Comment: If doing it I am violating some design principle in rest

Comment: I don't think it matters.  In all likelihood, you're not building a REST interface; this is simply a JSON web service.  Read https://restfulapi.net/ and see if your service meets the criteria provided there.

Answer (score 3):

> Because it's the same URI, can I do that?

Because the method is POST: yes, you can.

Consider the example of the world wide web; GET fetches a rich HTML document, with lots of interesting links, and images, and scripts.  POST, on the other hand, just delivers a bunch of encoded key value pairs.

And it all works just fine.